# Error in Undefined variable: languageID in Opencart 2.3.0.2

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.3

Am having a small issue in my site related tab in both Arabic and English interface it's showing in English, Really i need someone to help me fix this issue also i'm getting this error:
I have already setup the name in translation files for both languages.

```
PHP Notice: Undefined variable: languageID in public_html/catalog/view/theme/marine/template/product/product_detail_hitech.tpl on line 254

<?php if( $productConfig['enable_product_customtab'] && isset($productConfig['product_customtab_name'][$languageID]) ) { ?>


PHP Notice: Undefined variable: languageID in public_html/catalog/view/theme/marine/template/product/product_detail_hitech.tpl on line 335

<?php if( $productConfig['enable_product_customtab'] && isset($productConfig['product_customtab_content'][$languageID]) ) { ?>
```

The code calling this:

```
<?php if ($products) { ?> 
  <li>
    <a href="#tab-related" data-toggle="tab">
      Related Products (<?php echo count($products); ?>)
    </a>
  </li> 
<?php } ?> 
<?php if( $productConfig['enable_product_customtab'] && isset($productConfig['product_customtab_name'][$languageID]) ) { ?> 
  <li>
    <a href="#tab-customtab" data-toggle="tab">
      <?php echo $productConfig['product_customtab_name'][$languageID]; ?>
    </a>
  </li> 
 <?php } ?>
```

Your help would be much appreciated.

[image: Screenshot]

```
            <?php if ($products) { ?>
        <li><a href="#tab-related" data-toggle="tab">Related Products (<?php echo count($products); ?>)</a></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if( $productConfig['enable_product_customtab'] && isset($productConfig['product_customtab_name'][$languageID]) ) { ?>
            <li><a href="#tab-customtab" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $productConfig['product_customtab_name'][$languageID]; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
```

the second one here is it:

```
  <?php if ($products) { ?>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-related">
        <div class="product-related"> <?php require( PAVO_THEME_DIR."/template/common/products_related.tpl" );  ?> </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: That error seems to be pretty clear, the variable `$productConfig['product_customtab_name'][$languageID]` is not defined when those lines are being called. Please show us how this variable is being set

Comment: here is a screenshot for the error place
http://prntscr.com/gk9blp
it's in Related products tab it should show in Arabic when the customer use Arabic Interface.

Comment: Where is this variable being set? Whats different about the other tabs? We cannot know what is wrong without more insight into the relevant code

Comment: please edit these into your post in the same way I added the first set

Comment: you still do not show how the `$productConfig['product_customtab_name'][$languageID]` is defined or set

Comment: Dear Will,
I have included the file link up there so you can check it.

Comment: Please include relevant code in the question, do not link to outside resources needed for answering the question

Comment: Dere Will,
I'm really getting confused here i have include the error i have also i have put the code line for the error what else do you want me to do i'm sorry i'm don't have that's much experience in programming i'm trying to learn to fix my site issue since the developer not helping at all.

Comment: I understand, the error you are getting is because the variable does not exist when your code tries to call it, the important bit of code to see that might resolve the problem is the place in the code where the variable is being defined

Comment: Where i can find that variable?

Comment: That's the problem